# How to get the "Authentication" Object with Spring WebFlux?

Tags: spring-security, spring-webflux

Using SpringMVC and Spring Security I can implement a Controller like this one (in Java):

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/auth")
class AuthController {
    private final AuthService authService;

    AuthController(AuthService authService) {
        this.authService = authService;
    }

    @GetMapping("/roles")
    Collection<String> findRoles(Authentication authentication) {
        final Object principal = authentication.getPrincipal();
        ...;
    }
}
```

But, how do I basically inject the object of `org.springframework.security.core.Authentication`
in a *handler* class (or in a *service* class) when using Spring *WebFlux* and Spring Security (incl.
the reactive parts)?

Comment: Don't you use `@Autowired private final Authentication authentication` ?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Can you try to rephrase your question above?

Comment: I mean you could try that. Inject `Authentication` object using `@Autowired`.

Comment: @AtaurRahmanMunna if I try to autowire `Authentication` I get the error _Could not autowire. No beans of 'Authentication' type found._

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are a lot of examples: 
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security

This one shows how to get Principal in case of rest controller:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/b6895e6359e404e4ea101b78eb3135612dfe1769/samples/javaconfig/hellowebflux/src/main/java/sample/HelloUserController.java#L35

And this one shows how to get Principal in case of webflux:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/b6895e6359e404e4ea101b78eb3135612dfe1769/samples/javaconfig/hellowebfluxfn/src/main/java/sample/HelloUserController.java#L37

Answer (score 2):

```
//@AuthenticationPrincipal Mono<UserLogin> principal
//@AuthenticationPrincipal Mono<Authentication> principal

@GetMapping("/me")
public Mono<Map<String, Object>> current(@AuthenticationPrincipal Mono<Principal> principal) {
    return principal
            .map(user ->
                    Map.of(
                            "name", user.getName(),
                            "roles", AuthorityUtils.authorityListToSet(((Authentication) user)
                                    .getAuthorities())
                    )
            );
}
```

You can also use :

```
 ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.getContext()
            .map(m->m.getAuthentication())
            .map(m->m.getPrincipal());
```